# Why can't I get JavaScript yield to work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run the code from here

[MDN: Generators and Iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Generators_and_iterators_%28merge_into_Iterators_and_Generators%29)

```
function fib() {
  var i = 0, j = 1;
  while (true) {
    yield i;
    var t = i;
    i = j;
    j += t;
  }
}

var g = fib();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(g.next());
}
```

I cannot get it working in Node.js, Chrome or Firefox

Comment: I get missing ; before statement

yield i;

Comment: I saw it, but it's working even w/o that.

Comment: What error do you get in Firebug? Chrome/Node's console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an EcmaScript.next feature that is being tested in newer versions of JavaScript interpreters.

[Mozilla's "Iterators and Generators"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) explains how to use them.

To see which browsers support which ES.next features, see [kangax's compatibility chart](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/) and [browser specific reports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla).  Although Chrome as a whole does not yet, jmar777 reports that V8 supports it (as of Aug 2013).

Comment: Heads up: at the time this answer was given it was correct, but Generators have progressed to draft specification now and have been implemented in V8 (and present in Node v0.11.x).

Comment: @jmar777, Please see my edits.  I rewrote to bring up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

If this code is executing in Node.js application on the server side it doesn't matter what browser you're using as this isn't the execution environment for that block of code - it's on your server and as far as i know Node.js is using a version of the V8 JS engine that doesn't yet have ES6 support.

Comment: Calling it "ES6" is premature.